# custom select box- when selecting option value, show corresponding data-image as selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

for this custom select box, what needs to be done to display an image which is associated to an option value in the select box placeholder.
http://jsfiddle.net/6eCFz/

in this code, how to use the data-attribute, **first**, to show an image associated with an option value as the selected value and **second**, to display tick marks when dropdown is opened to indicate the selected value.

Additionally, there are minor bugs:

- a code for unique selection, for two select box filled with same options, does not seem to work.

  ```
  $("#c_id1").change(function(){
   $("#c_id2 option:hidden").show();
    if($(this).val().length ){
     $("#c_id2 option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").hide();
    }
  });
  $("#c_id2").change(function(){
   $("#c_id1 option:hidden").show();
    if($(this).val().length ){
     $("#c_id1 option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").hide();
    }
  });
  ```

  http://jsfiddle.net/73epV/ - (vanilla script as proof-of-concept)
  also, it does not ensures uniqueness onLoad
- after triggering the dropdown, if mouse is moved away without first hovering over the option list, the dropdown does not close.

lots of love for any help :)
thanks

Comment: Would be great if you could explain in detail.. I could not understand what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: i have put up everything where i am finding issues. is there any way to show a small image instead of the text which is selected from the dropdown options?

Comment: pls chk dis out - http://jsfiddle.net/6eCFz/